# Display category name next to product name on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to add the category name next to the product name on my woocommerce page. I would like to displays it because of SEO reasons, so that Google knows that this product belongs to this category.

My code looks like this at the moment

```
 the_title( '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>  <?php echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id()) ?>'  );
```

I tried to get it done by adding

`<?php echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id()) ?>`

but there is no category name and dev consolse etc also shows no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead try to replace your code with the following:

```
the_title( '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' ); 
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat' );
$term  = reset($terms);
echo $term->name;
```

It should work.

Comment: Hi, by adding this code it's hiding the product name and only shows the categories, as a breadcrumb, it should be only Product name Active Category. https://s16.directupload.net/images/190318/66jthrsf.png

Comment: @p_e_88 Made an update that will display only the first product category…